# How do you disable the CAPS LOCK key "delay" on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, delay, capslock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eliminate MacBook CapsLock delay](https://superuser.com/questions/317900/eliminate-macbook-capslock-delay)

When you press **caps lock** key on an Apple Mac OS X keyboard, either on a MacBook or aluminum keyboard, there's a slight delay of about 1/3rd of a second before it engages. No other keys on the keyboard experience this AFAIK.

If you're a fast typist, and want the caps lock key to respond instantly when pressed like any other key on the keyboard, this behavior is extremely annoying. Typically you're typing along, press caps lock quickly, continue typing, and then realize that caps lock did not engage/disengage. You delete whatever you just typed, jam the caps lock key down with all your might, visually see the green light turn on/off, and continue typing. While this only costs a few seconds, the added mental frustration and broken-typing-flow reduces productivity.

How do you remove the delay on the caps lock key so it toggles instantly when pressed on Mac OS X?

Comment: You remap the useless thing to control and relieve your emacs pinky in the bargin?