# Removing CapsLock delay on OSX - High Sierra v. 10+

Tags: macos, keyboard

Is there a reliable way to remove/disable/terminate the built-in "feature", CapsLock delay?

- Setting the CapsLock key to 'None' in Keyboard Modifier keys... settings, saving, then setting CapsLock to CapsLock again - didn't work.
- Enabling Slow keys and setting key repeat to 0 is not a viable solution as it makes the keyboard's KeyRepeat impractical to use.

Thus, I'm looking for more reliable solutions at this moment. Installed Karabiner Elements 12+ version, experimenting with it as I write here.

If someone has already solved this issue, please share your case.

Comment: checkout my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/317900/eliminate-macbook-capslock-delay/1429496#1429496

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eliminate MacBook CapsLock delay](https://superuser.com/questions/317900/eliminate-macbook-capslock-delay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.

Karabiner Elements, ver. 11.6.0 works great (do not use any >11.6.0 ver. for this) as it has, in 'Virtual keyboard' section, Capslock delay field where the default value is set to 0.

Karabiner be blessed.

KE download: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to use Karabiner for that, I've written a very small, open source tool just for that:

https://github.com/gkpln3/CapsLockNoDelay

Comment: Nice work, thanks for sharing!