# Macbook Pro 14 2021 caps lock issue

Tags: macbook, capslock

so I got a macbook pro 14 inch 2021, and I got two keyboards installed on it - English and Hebrew. When I type in english, everything is fine, but when I type in hebrew and wanna add something in english caps, I wanna use the caps lock to enable full caps english, however, it just enables lower case english.

Is there a way to make the caps lock work in full caps in the hebrew keyboard? This is how it always worked in windows computers (I just recently made the transition to mac)

**I'm currently using this little thing: https://superuser.com/a/1598700**

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at this other question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/229338/24324

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I changed my keyboard from 'Hebrew' to 'Hebrew-PC' like someone said on that question you linked, and it works now. Many many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

A brief press of the capslock key on a Mac can [be configured to change the language](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-your-mac-mchlp1406/mac):

> Switch between languages when writing by selecting the language you want to use in the Input menu. You can also set up your Mac to quickly switch between languages using your keyboard.
> ...
> Use the Caps Lock key: If you set an option in Input Sources preferences to change input sources by using the Caps Lock key or a dedicated language switching key

If you want it to write all caps (regardless of language) you need to press the capslock key slightly longer. The LED then should turn on, indicating that it's in capslock mode. No language switch should occur.

If you want to change this behaviour you can check [this other post](https://superuser.com/q/317900/141595).

Comment: Thank you. I am already using that little fix someone compiled there, but I'm still having the issue with the lower caps. Pressing slightly longer doesn't seem to fix it either. Any other idea?

Comment: Oh ok. Can you please edit your question to include everything you've tried already such that I (or anybody else) doesn't have to waste time suggesting things that don't work for you? When you write "that little fix", which of the 10 answers do you refer to?

Comment: Sorry. I used this: https://superuser.com/a/1598700

Comment: Got any idea about this?

Comment: I don't really get the problem. I just installed the Hebrew keyboard myself and for me it works as follows: Type in English; *long press CapsLock*, type in Hebrew; *short then long press CapsLock*, type in all caps in English; *short press Capslock twice*, type in Hebrew; Which part is not working for you or are you trying to change?

Comment: Since I'm using that little fix that removes the delay from the caps lock, the long press and short press things don't work

Comment: That's to be expected, right? I don't understand what you want to achieve. Can you perhaps edit your question to clarify? Perhaps indicate how it worked before the little fix, how it works now and how you want it to work?

Comment: Its simple - when i type in hebrew, then turn on caps lock regularly, it will write in lowercase english instead of uppercase english

Comment: Is that how it was before the little fix or after?

Comment: it was both before AND after